# Difference between FLAX and pytorch

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, pytorch

I am going through a code written in FLAX instead of pytorch .Can someone please explain what is the difference between these two deep learning frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Flax](https://github.com/google/flax) is a high-level library built on top of [Jax](https://github.com/google/jax), which is a recent numerical framework that allows to build differentiable models. Compared to PyTorch, Jax (and so Flax) follows the principles of *functional programming*: immutable objects, functions are fist-class, and stateless computation, to name a few. Pytorch, instead, follows an object-oriented programming paradigm where you represent your models as objects rather than the application of a function.

Basically, Jax and Pytorch implement the same thing with two different philosophies. Moreover, Jax is gathering attention thanks to its improved reproducibility since it is designed around stateless functions.

Comment: Hi got a doubt ..Is FLAX is optimised better than Pytorch or not? I am trying to convert a FLAX model to pytorch which has used nearly more than 10 Multi Layer Preceptrons for training the model.

Comment: @sripathiakhil I haven't done any benchmark, but I'll expect similar performance.